# Obtaining a 3D model from a 2D set of images

Tags: 3d-view, image, 2d

**Hello there.** I recently received a set of mr images and I want to make a 3D model of them. For this reason, I created many floors and put different textures on them.

**here is the result =**

[image]

but this process is not practical. Also, it's really **hard** to render this model in **eevee mode**. because this process is **very hard on my computer**. and there are spaces between images in this process.

That's why I don't like this method. If there is a method you can recommend instead of this method, I would be very happy if you indicate.

***Good day to everyone!***

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the specific data your MRI machine can generate, but it seems there is a 2015 DICOM plugin working for Blender 2.69+ to bring MRI scanned data into Blender:
https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-analyse-dicom-3d-models/641397
Also, just to clarify, so you can mark this answer as positive:

1. don't concentrate in the entire model as 1 piece. You need to "dissect" each part (and each modeled part): Skull, inner canals, nerves etc.. It's a process. Yes, you will NOT have "back faces for ocular regions, in general all occluded structures will be hollowed" and empty.
2. Edit (and model / cure / remesh) as you go. I don't know if your requirement needs to present accurate representation of a certain internal cranial structure, but if it's for artistic purposes, I think the above plugin does a great job.

Comment: thanks for your response. but this plugin is not working properly in my blender. Even though I can install the plugin, it doesn't show up on the left side. do you know any solution?

also 3D Slicer could not be downloaded. gave an error

Comment: you need to download a legacy blender (I think this version was 2.69)

Comment: Are ".dcm" files required for this plugin to work?